# Nondeterministic SSBO has GL_BUFFER_DATA_SIZE too small after glBufferData

Tags: opengl, shader-storage-buffer, buffer-objects

I seem to have nondeterministic data in my Shader Storage Buffer.

I used `apitrace` to inspect the state machine and noticed the following sequence of function calls in the trace:

```
glBindBuffer (GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BUFFER, 3);
glBufferData (GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BUFFER, 36, NULL, GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW);
glBufferSubData (GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BUFFER, 0, 4, [binary data, size = 4 bytes])
glBufferSubData (GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BUFFER, 4, 32, [binary data, size = 32 bytes])
```

This appears to be correct according to the higher-level application code, it matches setting this

```
layout (std140) buffer Components
{
    int count;
    vec4 colour [];
}
b_components;
```

to a length-prefixed array `glm::vec4[2]`.

However, `apitrace` shows that `GL_BUFFER_DATA_SIZE` is 32, not 36, at every stage in the above trace.

Also, here's an inspection of the SSBO:

[image]

`Components.colour[0]` has `GL_ARRAY_SIZE`=0 (shouldn't this be nonzero?) and `GL_OFFSET`=16 (shouldn't this be 4?)

The program is very simple, so for good measure, here's the full trace (this is for Frame 1, the `glBufferData(...,36,...)` was in Frame 0 and has not been repeated):

[image]

1. Shouldn't the SSBO have `GL_BUFFER_DATA_SIZE`=36, given my call to `glBufferData`? If so, is this a driver bug? If its stated size of 32 is correct, can you please explain how that makes sense?
2. Are the `GL_ARRAY_SIZE` and `GL_OFFSET` correct?
3. Given that inspecting the `glBufferSubData` calls, my array `glm::vec4[2]` describes correct, deterministic data, is there anything in this trace which would explain why, when I read `b_components.colour[i]` within `for (int i = 0; i < b_components.count; ++i)` that I get nondeterministic results?

Comment: Why are you binding a random integer instead of a value from `glGenBuffers`? That's only legal in compatibility OpenGL.

Comment: It **is** from `glGenBuffers`, I'm just not showing you the whole program. Also why have you marked this a duplicate? I see nothing there about unexpected `GL_BUFFER_DATA_SIZE` values?

Comment: It's easy to look up the fact that the buffer data size is the minimum size of a buffer needed for an indexed binding point, so I assume you know that. Given the correction to your misunderstanding of how `std140` layout works (which is what the duplicate supplies), that should be all you need to understand why 36 is not an appropriate minimum size for your storage block as it is defined, and why 32 makes far more sense.